# Why did Parthavi's father not resort to honor killing in Dhadak?

Tags: plot-explanation, dhadak

[Honor killing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honor_killing) is murdering a family member that has brought shame or dishonor upon the family, community or religion. Caste system is alive in India & across castes, a women's conduct is given very high importance in calculating family honor. Honor killing is prevalent in (Northern) India, where a girl from upper caste is murdered by her family for marrying, eloping and/or having sexual relations with a boy from lower caste.

*Dhadak* is an official remake (in Hindi) of a popular Marathi (language) movie *Sairat*. *Sairat* is a movie about honor killing where, a girl from upper caste elopes, marries & settles down with a child, with a boy from lower caste. The girls father sends henchmen to murder the girl & boy. Their child survives as he's not home when the henchmen arrive.

*Dhadak* is faithful to *Sairat* except at the end when the henchmen murder the boy & the child but leave the girl alive. Although all 3 of them are in the house for the henchmen to kill, they wait till the girl is out of the house & then kill the boy & their child.

**Why did the father not want to honor kill his daughter?** Especially because a prior scene shows that he loses an election to his rival due to said dishonor. His elected rival makes a jive at him to first take care of his daughter before thinking of the electorate.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, *Dhadak* is a remake of movie *Sairat*. But the climax is different in Dhadak.

In Dhadak, the heroine's brother and his friends kill the Hero and Child.

In Sairat, the hero and heroine get killed, leaving the child orphaned.

Dhadak ending was more heartbreaking than Sairat. Seeing the people, you love most in this world die in front of you, can't even imagine the pain. In the act of vengeance, the father decides to kill the two people her daughter loves the most,  Because of her, he lost power, which is the only thing he loves. For him killing her won't be enough.

The ending has the same effect but is slightly different. Even for people who have seen Sairat, you feel a jolt and shock. It’s also left somewhat open-ended if that’s the absolute end of what happens. I think the director Shashank Khaitan was right to change the ending slightly to still give that shock to all viewers, even those who had seen the original Sairat.

<sup>[refer](https://www.quora.com/What-happens-at-the-end-of-the-movie-Dhadak-2018-film-Is-the-ending-the-same-as-Sairat)</sup>